# Returning Array with-in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to ask - How can I return/make array with-in a `foreach` loop?

**Here is my code**

```
function getAllUsers() {
   $dir = "users/";
   $fl = scandir($dir);
   $cnt = 0;
   foreach (scandir($dir) as $fl) {
       if ($fl !== '.') {
           if ($fl !== '..') {
                if ($fl !== 'index.php') {
                    $pr = $fl;
                    $fl1 = scandir($dir . '/' . $fl);
                    $cnt++;
                    return $fl1[3]; //Here I want a array for file inside 'users\'.
                }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Thanks for giving answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically: you can not.
upon using return, the current function returns the value and stops execution.

return is by definition the end of the function.

but you can save the data you want to return in an array and then return the whole thing:

```
function getAllUsers() {
   $dir = "users/";
   $fl = scandir($dir);
   $cnt = 0;
   $result = []; //initiating the array
   foreach (scandir($dir) as $fl) {
       if ($fl !== '.') {
           if ($fl !== '..') {
                if ($fl !== 'index.php') {
                    $pr = $fl;
                    $fl1 = scandir($dir . '/' . $fl);
                    $cnt++;
                    $result[] = $fl1[3]; //adding your value to the array
                }
           }
       }
   }
   return $result;
}
```

Edit: If your PHP-Version mucks about the *$result = [];* you can use the "old" style *$result = array();* instead

Comment: no we don't, we want to add the variable in an array, not append it to a string.

Answer (score 2):

**Generators: Solution for PHP >= 5.5.**

If you want the function to return a value for each element in the loop back from the function use a generator:

```
/**
 * @return Generator|Iterator
 */
function getAllUsers() {
    $dir = "users/";
    $fl = scandir($dir);
    $cnt = 0;
    foreach (scandir($dir) as $fl) {
        if ($fl !== '.') {
            if ($fl !== '..') {
                if ($fl !== 'index.php') {
                    $pr = $fl;
                    $fl1 = scandir($dir . '/' . $fl);
                    $cnt++;
                    yield $fl1[3]; //Here I want a array for file inside 'users\'.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Loop over
foreach (getAllUsers() as $file) {

}

// Or one at a time
$generator = getAllUsers();
$file1 = $generator->current();
```

The other solutions here are more feasible however, this solution is mostly useful for implementing the `IteratorAggregate` interface, or creating co-routines.

Comment: My PHP version is `5.3.5`

Comment: That must really suck mate.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using an array. like below..

```
function getAllUsers() {
   $dir = "users/";
   $fl = scandir($dir);
   $cnt = 0;
   $array = array();
   foreach (scandir($dir) as $fl) {
       if ($fl !== '.') {
           if ($fl !== '..') {
                if ($fl !== 'index.php') {
                    $pr = $fl;
                    $fl1 = scandir($dir . '/' . $fl);
                    $cnt++;
                    $array[$fl] = $fl1[3]; //Push values in array for each user.                    
                }
           }
       }
   }
  return $array;
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: This not worked for me. It showing up error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\user_controll.php on line 27`

Comment: `$arr = [];` is line 27

Comment: replace this $arr = []; with $arr = array();